# UNIX- Identify which processes are running more that 6hours

Tags: process, process-management

I need to know which processes are running more than 6 hours in UNIX. How can I find those out?

Comment: Care to share what flavor of unix this is?

Comment: Most versions of `ps aux` show the column `START` with the start time or date.

Comment: If you are looking to limit CPU time per process, look at [pam_limits](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_limits.html).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you have available the general approach might be:

```
ps -o pid,lstart
```

and run a for loop over the results using something like:

```
date -j -f %c "$sdate" +%s
```

to convert the date to a UNIX timestamp. From there something like:

```
time=$((`date +%s`-`date -j -f %c "$sdate" +%s`))
echo $time
```

should give you the number of seconds that the process has been running. converting to hours is then trivial.

The short and long is that you will end up writing a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function to Get Process elapse time in minutes

```
GetProcTime() {
    local p=$1
    ps -eao "%C %U %c %t" | 
    awk "/$p/"'{print $4}' | 
    awk -F":" '{{a=$1*60} {b=a+$2}; if ( NF != 2 ) print b ; else print $1 }'
}
```

**Test**

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# GetProcTime monit
10
root@ubuntu:/tmp# if [[ $(GetProcTime monit) -ge 360 ]]; then echo "Process is running more than 6 hrs"; else echo "OK"; fi
OK
root@ubuntu:/tmp# GetProcTime init
466
root@ubuntu:/tmp# if [[ $(GetProcTime init) -ge 360 ]]; then echo "Process is running more than 6 hrs"; else echo "OK"; fi
Process is running more than 6 hrs
```

Answer (score 0):

this command will output process which running more than n hour from yesterday.
Process scans only today's processes.

```
ps -Ao ppid,pid,user,stime,cmd --sort=-pcpu | awk -v dateee=$(date +%H) '{ if (substr($4,3,1) ==":"  && ( dateee-substr($4,1,2) > 5 ))   print }'
```

you can change below part according your requirement. Example 5 hour.

```
dateee-substr($4,1,2) > 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly, and in the C/POSIX locale, you should be able to rely on `ps -o etime` giving you the elapsed time in a format like `[dd-]hh:mm:ss`. So processes that have been running for at least 6 hours would be the ones where there is a non-zero `dd-` part or when the `hh` part is greater than 06, so:

```
LC_ALL=C ps -Ao etime,pid |
  LC_ALL=C awk '$1 ~ /[1-9].*-|([1-9].|0[6-9]):..:/ {print $2}'
```

Would report the pids of the processes that have been running for more than 6 hours.

Note that a process can (and often does) run more than one command in its lifetime.